# Parsing string either regular expression or by comma separated in MsSql

Tags: sql-server, regex, string, parsing

I have posted before about parsing here using mssql which will parse comma separated strings. It worked fine but it only posted in 1 column. So all parsed strings are posted or shown in a single column only as I wanted it to show 1 column per 1 parsed string. Now my problem is I have a string which separates 3 first string by comma but the rest was not separated by comma but instead I have to parse it using regular expression. Is there a way to parse and return it one result per column and also to parse using comma separated way and regular expression.

Here's my code for parsing

```
USE [SMSGPS]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ufn_Parserstring]    Script Date: 11/24/2014 9:26:44  AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Parserstring] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(max) )
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(max) )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(max)

WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
BEGIN
SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                        LEN(@StringInput)))
SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                             ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput), 0),
                             LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
VALUES ( @String )
END

RETURN
END
```

When I use the code above using the code below it returns results in 1 column only which i wanted to show 1 result per column

Here's how I call the function

```
DECLARE @str2 varchar(max)
SET @str2  = (SELECT TOP 1 smsmsg FROM GPRSIN)

SELECT String as [Method2] from [dbo].[ufn_Parserstring] ( replace(@str2,';',',')) 

Go
```

This works only when I use this kind of string which has only comma and semi colon at the first 3 string then it will parse the first 2 then copy the rest
**351856040489593,241111;1R,141119040115,A,1422.1425N,12103.1746E,0.0,151,1.8,01000006;**

as you can see it has comma till the end. But when I use the string below
**351856045173481,RA1;1000V1430.4358N12100.0132E000.0170.601.0000-6002022221114CEA1120018613D000000,,,,,,,,**

Now I'm stuck here for almost 4 days now and I need all the help I can get. Thank you all in advance for all the help. I really thank you guys all.

The result for the first thing is like this (comma separated till the end)
[image]

Here's the string which is not comma separated until the end

[image]

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: Results may differ because the string itself is not constant....But with regards to constant result, the first result attached pic is the result I want but instead of having it in 1 column, i would like it to be 1 result per column.

Comment: `1000V1430.4358N12100.0132E000.0170.601.0000-6002022221114CEA1120018613D000000` what should be expected result for this

Comment: 1000     
V     
1430.4326N     
12100.0162E     
000.03     
42.20      
2.0000      
90027     
0923111     
4D     
3A     
3    
120019815    
1000000    I put spaces between results different from the one above

Comment: you mean you want 1000 in one row ? V in another 1430 in another ? or all on the same row ?

Comment: "But with regards to constant result, the first result attached pic is the result I want but instead of having it in 1 column, i would like it to be 1 result per column" can you show us what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I want all result in 1 row but in different columns

Comment: Are the names of the columns known? Can you have `ufn_Parserstring` put those names next to the values? If so then you wanna look at **[PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it if the number of columns is unknown. I changed your `ufn` to have an identity columns which I can later use to **[PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)** the resultset. This has to happen in *dynamic SQL* if the columns are unknown.

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Parserstring] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(max),  @separators varchar(255))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE (
    id int identity,
    [String] VARCHAR(max)
) AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(max)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0 BEGIN
        SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(patindex('%[' + @separators + ']%', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(patindex('%[' + @separators + ']%', @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
        VALUES ( @String )
    END

    RETURN
end
go

declare @str2 varchar(max), @cols varchar(255)
set @str2 = '351856040489593,241111;1R,141119040115,A,1422.1425N,12103.1746E,0.0,151,1.8,01000006;'

if object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null
    drop table #Temp

select *
into #Temp
from dbo.ufn_Parserstring(@str2, ',;')

select @cols = stuff((
    select ', [' + cast(id as varchar(3)) + ']'
    from #Temp
    for xml path(''), type
).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')

exec('
    select *
    from #Temp t
    pivot (
        min(t.String)
        for id in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p
');
```